# ActiveRecord select().where() returns SQL that starts with SELECT COUNT - I don't want COUNT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple select().where() statement in rails that is returning SQL that starts with "SELECT COUNT(...", and I don't know where the COUNT is coming from and don't want it.

I've done a lot of googling, but since COUNT is such a prevalent term I haven't been able to find any relevant answers.

This is the code that's doing it:

`@properties = Property.select("property.*").where("(address1 LIKE '%528 Alameda%')")`

This is what I got (copied from the error message on the webpage):

`` SELECT COUNT(property.*) FROM `property` WHERE ((address1 LIKE '%528 Alameda%')) ``

This is what I expected:

`` SELECT property.* FROM `property` WHERE ((address1 LIKE '%528 Alameda%')) ``

Why is COUNT() getting added and how can I get rid of it?  Thanks!

**EDIT**

Turns out I was looking in the wrong place.  It had nothing directly to do with this code:

`@properties = Property.select("property.*").where("(address1 LIKE '%528 Alameda%')")`

Rather, later in the code, I called `@properties.count` which was generating the SQL

`` SELECT COUNT(property.*) FROM `property` WHERE ((address1 LIKE '%528 Alameda%')) ``

Which was crashing.  The question is: what's wrong with that SQL?

Comment: Can you try to see if `Property.unscoped { Property.select("property.*").where("(address1 LIKE '%528 Alameda%')") }` returns the same?

Comment: It may be worth adding the Property model to your question. Also, do you get the same result using arel? `Property.where(Property.arel_table[:address1].matches('%528 Alameda%'))`

Comment: Are you using pagination of any kind? Most pagination libraries will run a count to determine number of pages from total results and per page count

Comment: Can you add the Property model so that we can help you?

Comment: The code in this question can't possibly explain this. I'm guessing that its pagination like @engineersmnky hinted or you're doing something in the view that causes a count query. You'll have to do a bit more legwork in tracking it down.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, thank you for your help.  Unscoped had the same problem, but as Max hinted at I was looking in the wrong place (rails noob).  I'm going to answer my own question in a moment.

Comment: @David - your suggestion did not cause the same problem, and got me thinking along some different lines which ultimately led to the solution which I'm going to post in a moment.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you for your suggestion... it was a count call that I was doing manually myself later in the code that was the problem.

Comment: @Haytham.Breaka Thank you for caring and wanting to help.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @max - you were right - I had to do more legwork and I tracked down where it was really happening and then found a solution which I'm going to post.

Answer (score 0):

`Property.where("address1 LIKE ?", "528 Alameda")`

Comment: For `LIKE` `%528 Alameda%` is not the same as `528 Alameda`.

Answer (score 0):

COUNT can only take 1 column name as a parameter.  So you can do COUNT(id), but you can't do COUNT(property.*), or COUNT(id, builder), etc.

The solution is to write `@properties.count(:id)`

Comment: A better idea is to use `.size`. It will use the length if the records are loaded and avoid a query and create `COUNT(*)` otherwise.

Comment: @max Even better!  Thanks so much!